# roslaunch leap_motion sensor_sender.launch not working

Tags: roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, whenever I try to execute the command line:

```
roslaunch leap_motion sensor_sender.launch
```

this shows up

```
... logging to /home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/roslaunch-JuanTelo-11993.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://JuanTelo:42806/ 

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: indigo
* /rosversion: 1.11.21

NODES
  /
    sender_freq (leap_motion/sender.py)

 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[sender_freq-1]: started with pid [12011]
[sender_freq-1] process has died [pid 12011, exit code -11, cmd /home/juantelo/catkin_ws/src/leap_motion/scripts/sender.py _freq:=0.01 __name:=sender_freq __log:=/home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/sender_freq-1.log].
log file: /home/juantelo/.ros/log/73513fa2-be34-11e7-86a9-1c394718bbbd/sender_freq-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

and it closes.

Anyone knows how I Can solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274646/roslaunch-leap_motion-sensor_sender.launch-not-working/) by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure about that one, but there is an alternative. [leap_motion_controller](https://github.com/UTNuclearRoboticsPublic/leap_motion_controller) If you're interested, I'll update the installation instructions.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2017-10-31**:
Yes please, if you can do that, it'd be great.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-10-31**:
Done! See the Readme in the package.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-10-31**:
You could have tried running your original launch file with output="screen" in the launch file... to possibly see more output on the screen. They didn't give you much to troubleshoot by.

**Comment by [JuanTelo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32449/juantelo/) on 2017-11-01**:
I made it, it works, tried with Rviz and I can see hands. I'm very grateful to you.